# R loop conditioning on previous results

Tags: r, for-loop

To illustrate my question, here is a demo shows what I am trying to do. My question is on how to set a loop in the `fun2`.

```
#generate demo data
set.seed(123)
n<-200
data<-data.frame(time=sample(0:5,n,T),
               out=sample(c(rbinom(n,1,0.3), rep(NA,40)),n),
               pred1=rnorm(n),
               pred2=rbinom(n,10,0.7),
               pred3=sample(1:2,n,T))

#function1 to impute the out with time<=i. 
#You need to install 'mice' package to run that.
fun1<-function(data, time, out, i, m){
            library(mice)
            if (sum(is.na(data[data[, time]<=i, out]))>=1) {compl<-complete(mice(data[data[, time]<=i, ], m=m))}
            else {compl=data[data[, time]<=i, ]}    
            return(compl)
            }
test<-fun1(data,"time","out",1,5)
test #out was imputed for time<=1           
fun2<-function(data, time, out,  m){
                        C1<-fun1(data, time, out, 1,  m)#impute the out for time<=1
            R1<-rbind(C1, data[data[, time]==(1+1),])#rbind the imputed out with the unimputed
                        C2<-fun1(R1, time, out, 2,  m)#impute the out for time<=2...
            R2<-rbind(C2, data[data[, time]==(1+2),])   
                        C3<-fun1(R2, time, out, 3,  m)
            R3<-rbind(C3, data[data[, time]==(1+3),])
                        C4<-fun1(R3, time, out, 4,  m)
            R4<-rbind(C4, data[data[, time]==(1+4),])
                        C5<-fun1(R4, time, out, 5,  m)
            return(C5)
    }
fun2(data,"time","out",5)
```

My question is how to set a loop for fun2 so that it works for any data set like the demo (no limits for the "time" values, here is 5)

Comment: For the generation of the test data, are you assuming `T==TRUE`; i.e., `replace=TRUE`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `fun2` with a maximum loop value, e.g. `iloop`, then

```
fun2<-function (data,time,out,iloop,m) {
    r <- list()
    for (j in 1:iloop) {
       r[[j]]<-  rbind(fun1(data,time,out,j,m),data[data[,time]==(j+1),])
    }
    return(r[[j]])
}
```

I may have missed a little there but the general idea should be clear.  Instead of all your separate `R1 R2 R3` I've assigned them as elements of a `list` .

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the `<<-` assignment operator, which allows you to modify a value outside of a function from within a function.  Typically I avoid using it, but in this case given you need to re-use a previous calculation, I don't really see an option.

```
fun2<-function(index, data, time, out,  m){
  R <- rbind(C, data[data[, time]==(index),])#rbind the imputed out with the unimputed
  C <<- fun1(R, time, out, index,  m)#impute the out for time<=2...  
}
C <- fun1(data, "time", "out", 1,  5)     # Need to initialize C
for(i in 2:5) fun2(i, data, "time", "out", 5)
C  # This now contains your result
```

Note that I cannot 100% verify this is doing what you want it to do because it seems `mice` has non-deterministic behavior (i.e. if I run your code twice, even excluding the data generation section, I get different answers).